# Failed to download JupyterHub via helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I am trying to download/install the jupyterhub helm chart.

```
> helm repo add jupyterhub https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/
"jupyterhub" has been added to your repositories

> helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "jupyterhub" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈

> helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --namespace jhub --version=0.8.2 --values config.yaml
Error: failed to download "jupyterhub/jupyterhub" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

(trying `helm repo update` again does not work)

When I look at my repos, I can see jupyterhub:

```
> helm repo list
NAME        URL
stable      https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
local       http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
jupyterhub  https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart/
```

what am i missing? could it be upstream repo server issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. The problem was that I had quotes around the version. it did not accept that. This works:

```
helm upgrade --install jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub --namespace jhub --version=0.8.2 --values config.yaml
```